# A proof of positive semi-definiteness

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ - symmetric matrix and $p\in \mathbb{R}^n, p\neq 0$. Prove that if $$(w-p)^\top A (w-p)\geq 0, \mbox{ for all }\;  w \; \mbox{  satisfying  }\; \|w \|=  \|p \|,$$
then $A$ is positive semidefinite.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Seems like it may help if you diagonalize it and try the contrary.

Answer (score 2):

To prove that $A$ is positive semidefinite, you need to prove that $v^TAv\geq 0$ for all $v\in \Bbb R^n$. Since $(tv)^TA(tv)=t^2(v^TAv)$ for all $t\in \Bbb R$, we can simply check that for every $v$ there exists $t_v\neq 0$ such that $(t_vv)^TA(t_vv)\geq 0$. Now it suffices to make sure $t_vv$ can be written as $w-p$ with $\|w\|=\|p\|$; thus we just need to to take $t_v$ such that
$$\|p\|^2=\|p+t_v v\|^2 = \|p\|^2+2t_v(p|v)+t_v^2\|v\|^2.$$
So if $(p|v)\neq 0$, we can simply take $t_v=\frac{-2(p|v)}{\|v\|^2}$.

All this shows that $v^TAv\geq 0$ for all $v\in \Bbb R^n\setminus \langle p\rangle ^T$. Let us denote $f:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$ the function $v\mapsto v^TAv$. Then $f^{-1}((-\infty,0))\subset \langle p\rangle ^T$, and $f$ is continuous, so $f^{-1}((-\infty,0))$ is open in $\Bbb R^n$. But a non-empty open subset of $\Bbb R^n$ cannot be contained in a proper hyperplane; thus $f^{-1}((-\infty,0))=\emptyset$, which proves that $f(v)=v^TAv\geq 0$ for all $v$.